# Create persistent Sqlite db in Windows phone 8

Tags: database, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am trying my hands on `Windows phone 8` applications and I am stuck into a weird situation here. I am using **sqlite** in order to create sqlite db and add values into the database. I am able to create the database and add the values in the database successfully but I am having a weird situation here.

Everytime I close the emulator and start the project again the database gets created again which should not be happening because I created the db the very first time I run the application.

Does anybody know why, and how I can prevent it from recreating the database each time?

```
public string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "aa.sqlite"));
private SQLiteConnection dtCon;

public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
CreateDatabase();
dtCon = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH);
var tp = dtCon.Query<Contacts>("select * from contacts").ToList();
}

private async void CreateDatabase()
{
bool isDatabaseExisting = false;
//Checking if database already exists
try
{
Windows.Storage.StorageFile storagefile = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("aa.sqlite");
isDatabaseExisting = true;
}
catch
{
isDatabaseExisting = false;
}
//if not exists then creating database
if (!isDatabaseExisting)
{
String str = System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "sqlite.db");
AddDataToDB(DB_PATH);
}
}
private void AddDataToDB(string str)
{
// Create the database connection.   
dtCon = new SQLiteConnection(str);
// Create the table Task, if it doesn't exist.   
dtCon.CreateTable<Contacts>();
Contacts oContacts = new Contacts();
oContacts.Name = "dfgdf";
oContacts.Detail = "asdfsf";
dtCon.Insert(oContacts);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Chubosaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29997122/4184842) says, closing and re-opening the emulator will remove all the apps. You can generally keep it running as long as you want and keep re-deploying your app to the emulator (although obviously rebooting the host PC will kill it).

You can save and restore the data from your emulator image via the `ISETool` command. See more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure when you close your emulator and restart, you're basically just uninstalling the application.  Which is why your files or not there anymore -- as it looks like you're storing your data in isolated storage.  I do not know if there is anyway around this.

You can buy a very cheap Windows 8/8.1 Phone and the files will persist until you manually uninstall the test application.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **Console.WriteLine("True");** and **Console.WriteLine("False");** into the expected places after checking **isDatabaseExisting** to see/understand what the code path really is.